# What has to be set in DesiredCapabilites to run Applications app?

Tags: java, android, appium

On the Android platform there is a menu which shows all installed applications. My goal is to test this menu using Appium and Java language.

As you can see in the attached image the package for this application is com.lge.launcher2 so the "appPackage" variable is known.

[image: UiAutomatorViewer]

The problem is that I have to set proper DesiredCapabilities for "appActivity" as well and I have no idea where I can find this name.
Using adb shell I have grabbed all installed applications and there is "package:/system/priv-app/LGHome.apk=com.lge.launcher2" but when I set my DesiredCapabilities like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.lge.launcher2");
caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.lge.launcher2.LGHome");
```

i got an error that "Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched!".

So how I can run this Application Menu?
Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by tapping on that launcher? Even if you manage to open through this method it won't work the same on a different company's emulator say Nexus or Samsung. On Nexus is it `com.google.launcher3`. If you want to open another app, you don't have to go that route.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You can try opening other app , minimize it and then find Apps by text on the screen & Click on Apps

Comment: @satyajit you're absolutelty right. But I wanted to do this only for testing purposes and I got stucked when I wanted to start it properly. That's way I asked about it.

Comment: You should add one more value in desired capability "caps.setCapability("app", "{Apkfile path}");" Also new appium you don't need to add "appPackage" and "appActivity" in desired Capability.

Answer (score 0):

you can automate apps using appium to learn. download any sample app to ur machine,

try adding ur app path that u have in ur local machine that need to be pushed to device using ,

```
 caps.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\...\\yourappname.apk");
```

to find the app activity name, in cmd prompt hit

```
aapt dump badging "fullpath to ur apk in machine"
```

scroll down and find the value of the parameter

```
launchable-activity
```

and replace it with your app package value in capablities

Comment: Thanks a lot but I know that :) My goal was to make some Appium tests without installing any app and I was confused how to do it in this particular example with Apps Menu. Rest of the tests were working properly so it is not the case.